# html page in app, reference css after corev15.css

Tags: css, app, cssregistration

I have a SharePoint app, where I am using an `html` page, not `.aspx`.

I referenced bootstrap, but the style for the buttons is being retrieved from `corev15app.css`, not from bootstrap (btn-primary).

How can I force the bootstrap library to be loaded after sharepoint css. I can't use `cssregistration`, right?

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: @PradipR. I don't want to override bootstrap.css classes. Seems you didn't get my question. There's a script corev15app.css, which is overriding bootstrap scripts.

Comment: It's not my css, it's bootstrap. Should I go into bootstrap file and write !important all over the classes?

Comment: can you give a try like this in dom ready $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.css' type='text/css' />"));

Comment: @PradipR. do I do that for every class in bootstrap? Sorry but it doesn't seem like a valid solution..

Comment: See this MSDN thread for more: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c3533f28-0624-4ff4-8856-b86041e11fab/sharepoint-2013-custom-master-page-with-bootstrap?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: @PradipR., then why corev15app.css isn't overriding my custom css. If I have custom css referenced and make a button background color red, sharepoint css will not override it. But if I use bootstrap classes for it, sharepoint will override it. Why?

Comment: I didn't get it. I have 2 external css files. One from bootstrap, which is bootstrap.css, and the other is my file style.css. I reference both of these files in the <head> tag. SharePoint overrides only bootstrap.css. Why it doesn't affect style.css?